# No analysable projects were found but some duplicate project IDs were found

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are integrating SonarQube Extension for TFS-VSTS into our build but when we build our project it is throwing an error as shown

> [error]No analysable projects were found but some duplicate project IDs were found. Possible cause: you are building multiple configurations (e.g. DEBUG|x86 and RELEASE|x64) at the same time, which is not supported by the SonarQube integration. Please build and analyse each configuration individually**. But we are not building multiple configurations in our project.

**FYR**: In our project build variables are queued as

BuildConfiguration : Release

BuildPlatform : Any CPU

Any hints ?

Comment: The issue got resolved by adding an argument as /p:DeployOnBuild=true  to Visual Studio Build task.